# When installing Levelplay, the Android Resolver gets stuck at 100% for hours and never completes

Tags: unity-game-engine, admob, ironsource

Following this video https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=sU5njx1jn8w and others, when I try to install admob for levelplay the Android Resolver runs for hours and never completes even though it shows 100%. It also takes up all available RAM on my machine.

I followed the steps of this video in order, but I couldn't get it to work.
I'm using a MacBook Pro with an M1 Pro chip and 32 GB of RAM

Answer (score 0):

I followed this tutorial for adding levelplay and ran into a snag.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=sU5njx1jn8w

If you are getting errors in your android build while following this tutorial, OR if your machine is taking hours resolving the AdMob dependencies, READ THIS!

TLDR;

- Update your project to the latest unity editor
- then do this gradle step before the next step -> https://youtu.be/sU5njx1jn8w?si=FVNARr5aXzlwcqd_&t=685
- then do this -> https://youtu.be/sU5njx1jn8w?si=H62I_RRbWtbG3CQK&t=433

HARDWARE

I'm am using Apple Silicon M1 Pro for my unity project.

UNITY CAN'T INSTALL ANDROID SDK 34 - FIX

I tried several times to install the IronSource Integration Manager (ISIM) in the instructions. The first time I did it, it took over an hour to resolve the android dependencies and then the build wouldn't work. I found there is a bug in the version of unity I was using 2022.3.5f1 and it was fixed in 2022.3.17f1. The bug was in trying to build with SDP 34 which is required for the version of the ISIM I was trying to run.

INSTALLING IS AND ADMOB - FAILED AFTER SEVERAL HOURS/ATTEMPTS

After upgrading my project to the newer version of unity, I was able to install ISIM but when I tried to add AdMob, it took HOURS and all RAM in the system and then some.... and failed. So I discarded those changes and I tried it again and again and of course it didn't work. I spent several hours trying to get this to work.

HOW TO FIX THIS

I found help here -> https://developers.google.com/admob/unity/quick-start

Go to Project Settings > Player > Android > Publishing Settings > Build and select:

- Custom Main Gradle Template
- Custom Gradle Properties Template

These instructions are in the video, but they are AFTER installing AdMob, however they need to be done BEFORE.

do this first -> https://youtu.be/sU5njx1jn8w?si=FVNARr5aXzlwcqd_&t=685

then do this -> https://youtu.be/sU5njx1jn8w?si=H62I_RRbWtbG3CQK&t=433